# Freeing array of structs inside struct

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct, free

I have two structs

```
struct obj_t {
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct cluster_t {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct obj_t *obj;
};
```

As you can see, there is pointer to first `obj_t` inside `cluster_t`

What I want to do is to free every obj_t from array inside cluster_t

Do I have to write it with `for` loop like this?

```
void clear_cluster(struct cluster_t *c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<c->size;i++)
    {
        free(&c->obj[i]);
    }
    free(c->obj);
}
```

Or is it ok to free the memory just like this ?

```
void clear_cluster(struct cluster_t *c)
{
    free(c->obj);
}
```

Comment: By the reverse of the sequence where you allocated.

Comment: *"As you can see array of `obj_t` is inside `cluster_t`"* -- I cannot see any array inside `cluster_t`. I can see a pointer but that's a different thing.

Comment: There neither is a pointer to array in your `struct`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be one `free()` for every `malloc()` you have, and executed in the opposite order from which it was allocated.

The field `obj` of `cluster_t` is a pointer to an array of `object_t`. This is probably allocated with one `malloc()` when initializing your `cluster_t` (something like `c->obj = malloc(c->capacity*sizeof(*c->obj))`), so it only needs to be freed with one call to `free()`. You would then want to free the `cluster_t` allocation itself (assuming it too was dynamically allocated):

```
free(c->obj);
free(c);
```

There would be a difference, however, if *each* `object_t` itself had a dynamic allocation within it. (In your example, `object_t` does not.) In that case, you would have needed to iterate through the array and `malloc()` an allocation when you created the array, and therefore do the reverse and `free()` each at the end.

Comment: @HynekBernard the `struct cluster_t` also has members `int size` and `int capacity` which suggest that the memory allocated to the member `struct obj_t *obj` might be expanded with `realloc()` one or more times. That counts as a single allocation and only needs one `free`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you allocated. It seems you did something like

```
struct cluster_t cluster;
cluster.obj = malloc(sizeof (struct obj_t) * SOMENUMBER);
```

in this case, `cluster.obj` is just a pointer to an array. All you need to do is

```
free(cluster.obj)
```

or

```
free(c->obj)
```

in that function which receives a pointer to `c`.

You only have to iterate over the array calling `free` if you have an array of pointers.

Remember that `&` takes the memory address of the variable. You don't free the pointer, you free the memory that the pointer points to. You will never do something like `free(&pointer)`.