# Allocated memory - Struct with array already alloc

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I've got the following example :

```
#define MAX_SIZE 32 

typedef struct T {
     int total_data;
     D *data;
} T;

typedef struct D {
     int type;
     char value[MAX_SIZE];  
} D;
```

I've got a part which extract and fill D* data;
And one who print it.

The part which extract and fill D extract data from a file.

```
void extract(T *_t) {
     // Open file
     fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &_t->total_data);
     _t->data = malloc(_t->total_data * sizeof(*_t->data);

     // Extract and fill 
     for ( i = 0; i < _t->total_data; i++) 
         fscanf(fp, "%d:%[^$]\n", &(_t->data[i].type), _t->data[i].value);
 }
```

The function which read looks like this :

```
void read(T *_t) {
    int i; 
    for( i = 0; i < _t->total_data; i++) 
         printf("%d - %s", _t->data[i].type, _t->data[i].value);
}
```

But I've got a crash .. 
I don't know why .. the code looks ok for me according to what I've found on the web.
Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Files look like that :

```
2
0:ABC
1:DEFGHI
```

For exemple

Comment: I have only looked at the code so far... always make sure malloc hasn't returned `NULL`. Especially given the fact you're reading from a file, you could run out of memory. Always assume you might run out of memory anyway :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeing array of structs inside struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950900/freeing-array-of-structs-inside-struct)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d\n", _t->total_data);
```

is invalid. `_t->total_data` is an int but you need a pointer to int in order to scan data.

Try

```
fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &_t->total_data);
                   ^
                   note
```

BTW: Didn't your compile give a warning for this ?

Comment: Well .. nope he did not >< I'll take a look ! Thanks

Comment: @kaldoran do you use the flags `-Wall -Wextra` with your compiler? Works with gcc g++ and clang (maybe others compilers too)